# How to get values of an item in the loop in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

### Problem:

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a value of a clicked item into another component

---

**See codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRXBNY

### In the codepen menu of an item is triggered by right click

Let's say we have a loop ([this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterator#introduction) iterator component) that's displaying all the items of object `items`

```
<v-data-iterator
  :items="items"
  hide-actions
  class="ma-4"
>
  <v-flex
    slot="item"
    slot-scope="props"
    xs12 sm6 md4 lg3
  >
    <v-card @contextmenu="show" class="ma-3 elevation-4">
      <v-card-title>
        <h4>{{ props.item.name }}</h4>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</v-data-iterator>
```

And we also have [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#example-absolute-without-activator) "menu" component in the same .vue component:

```
<v-menu 
  absolute
  offset-y 
  :position-x="x"
  :position-y="y" 
  v-model="showMenu"
>
  <v-list>
    <p class="white ma-3">menu for item: [TITLE]</p>
    <v-list-tile 
       v-for="item in menuItems" 
       :key="item.title" @click=""
    >
      <v-list-tile-title>
        {{ item.title }}
      </v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-text-field 
      class="ma-3" 
      label="rename">
    </v-text-field>  
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

### Question:

How do we trigger the menu component and pass the data of that particular item in it (so that we can do something with it)? As an example I put this `menu for item: [TITLE]` paragraph there, I don't understand how do we pass the title of the clicked item there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem a bit messy to me (i'm not very familiar with Vuetify), but the first solution that comes to my mind is to pass `item` object to the handler. So your code goes as:

```
<v-card @contextmenu="show($event, props.item)" class="ma-3 elevation-4"></v-card>
```

Then once the event is fired and handler function is called you can store the item you clicked on:

```
show (e, item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    e.preventDefault()
// ...
```

Now you can use the item inside the model component as:

```
<v-list>
    <p class="white ma-3">
        menu for item: {{selectedItem.name}}
    </p>
//...
```

Full demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    show (e, item) {
      this.selectedItem = item;
      e.preventDefault()
      this.showMenu = false
      this.x = e.clientX
      this.y = e.clientY
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.showMenu = true
      })
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    selectedItem: {},    
    showMenu: false,
    menuItems: [
      { title: 'copy' },
      { title: 'paste' },
      { title: 'delete' }
    ],
    items: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Eclair'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Cupcake'
        }
      ]
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" >
  <v-app id="inner" class="grey lighten-3"> 
    <h1 class="ma-2 ml-4">right click on an item to trigger menu</h1>
<!--  ITEMS ON THE PAGE -->
    <v-data-iterator
      :items="items"
      hide-actions
      class="ma-4"
    >
      <v-flex
        slot="item"
        slot-scope="props"
        xs12 sm6 md4 lg3
      >
        <v-card @contextmenu="show($event, props.item)" class="ma-3 elevation-4">
          <v-card-title>
            <h4>{{ props.item.name }}</h4>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-data-iterator>
    
<!-- MENU COMPONENT -->
    <v-menu 
      absolute
      offset-y 
      :position-x="x"
      :position-y="y" 
      v-model="showMenu"
    >
      <v-list>
        <p class="white ma-3">menu for item: {{selectedItem.name}}</p>
        <v-list-tile 
           v-for="item in menuItems" 
           :key="item.title" @click=""
        >
          <v-list-tile-title>
            {{ item.title }}
          </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-text-field 
          class="ma-3" 
          label="rename">
        </v-text-field>  
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you for the answer and the explanation!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you as well, you guys are awesome. People on stack overflow are always ready to help, that's nice to see!